# Include XCFrameworks to a Podspec

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec, xcframework

I've got a static library, compiled for multiple architectures, included in a XCFramework.

It looks like this :

```
 | framework_1.xcframework
 |---- _CodeSignature
 |---- Info.plist
 |---- ios-arm64_arm64e
       |---- Headers
       |---- libframework.a
 |---- ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
       |---- Headers
       |---- libframework.a
 |---- macos-arm64_arm64e_x86_64
       |---- Headers
       |---- libframework.a
```

I'm developing beside it an iOS framework, with a Podspec, looking like this :

```
Spec do |spec|
 spec.information

 spec.subspec 'XCFrameworkPod' do |xcframework|
  xcframework.vendored_frameworks = 'path/to/framework_1.xcframework'
 end
```

I've managed to include my headers, by specifying this :

```
  xcframework.source_files = 'path/to/framework_1.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Headers/**/*.h'
```

This way, my headers are available in my project. But when I try to use one of them, it doesn't compile. I've the following error :

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/clang/include/inttypes.h'
> Include of non-modular header inside framework module: '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/MyPod/XCFrameworkPod/Headers/header.h'

How to integrate correctly the xcframework & headers?

I've tried setting 'Clang allow non-modular headers', but it doesn't work in a Swift project.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

The `source_files` attribute should not be used together with the `vendored_frameworks` attribute. All the headers should be embedded in the `vendored_frameworks`. Here's an [example](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/8.9.1/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json).

Comment: If anyone was curious to see it in a non-json format: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec

Comment: I'm struggling to get this to work.  I found a simple example, but the xcframework is not downloaded.  Is this sample incorrect now?  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/examples/Vendored%20Framework%20Example/Example%20Pods/VendoredFrameworkExample.podspec